# Bitwise shift Data in Swift

Tags: swift, rotation, bit, shift

I have a data object, containing multiple bytes of information. For an algorithm I need this Data to be shifted left or right by one bit. Is there any efficient way to do this?

I tired implementing it something like this, but I believe this is highly ineffective solution:

```swift
fileprivate let LSBofByte: UInt8 = 0x01 // 0000 0001
fileprivate let MSBofByte: UInt8 = 0x80 // 1000 0000

extension Data {
    mutating func leftShiftByteArray() {
        self[0] <<= 1 // Shift first byte
        for i in 1...self.count-1 {
            if (self[i] & MSBofByte) == MSBofByte {
                self[i-1] |= LSBofByte // Carry the leading 1 from current byte to previous
            }
            self[i] <<= 1 // Shift other bytes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe this to be highly ineffective?

Comment: Based on my measures with Inspector. Most of the time my app is shifting bytes with very high CPU usage. :)

Comment: Bitwise shifting a byte array *is* inefficient. What do you need it for?

Comment: @MartinR not an array, Data object instance.

Comment: `Data` stores its value as a continuous block of bytes in memory, but that is not my point. I am asking  *why* you need the bit shifting.

Comment: I implement a data encoding/decoding algorithm, namely MSBST (also known as serial encoding), which involves bit shift on the whole dataset multiple times during the process.

Comment: I am not familiar with that algorithm. But if the purpose is to access all bits sequentially then it is more efficient to use an index into the data (for the current byte) and a bit mask. So you can access single bits without modifying the underlying data.